# Make a Firebase Database reset at 00:00

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making an application to make daily payments, so I wanted that every day at 00:00, the payment data of the Firestore would be reset, for the customer to make the payment again.

Thats a way to do that with some back-end code on the Firebase Server?

Comment: have you checked this? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions
You need to upgrade your plan to Blaze plan if you wan to use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create [scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) for that with higher timeout, that will delete your collection. Function code will be very similar to [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections)